# LDAP - benefits and challenges instead of local user management

Tags: ldap, kerberos

I have been looking at LDAP + Kerberos for my setup.
I am wondering what is the benefits and challenges with using LDAP + Kerberos instead of local user manangement. I know that LDAP can be used for authorization and storing user information, while kerberos is for authentication.

Answer (score 2):

In a LAN with 1 or more servers, and a bunch of workstation, you can log on to any of them provided you have been granted access, that comes from LDAP.
It provides 1 place to manage users - not running around and create the same user on all the various boxes, thereby ensuring a uniform spelling of Names - and securing that all the needed groups the user belongs to are there, no-matter on which computer the user is logging in.  So Ease of Use!
One place to backup all the users, with all their rights and groups!